# Reading values from test fixture Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm new to Cypress and started playing around with fixtures.I'm trying to read values from a JSON file and then assert the values in a test.

Here is my code

```
it('Fixture test' ,() => {
    cy.fixture('AllNotificationStates').then(notifications => {
        for(let n in notifications) {
            cy.intercept('GET', '**/api', { fixture: 'AllNotificationStates.json' });

            cy.wrap(notifications[n])
            .should('be.an', 'object')
            .and('contain', {
                rowId: 1,
                streamId: "33e24004-04ff-4c44-8d59-c8752b0f43d7",
                notificationStatus: "Sent",
              });
        }
    });
})
```

What this does is assert that the properties within the JSON file match the values I expect. What I'm trying to do is read the values from the fixture file save them to an object and then assert them in my test. So for example the property rowId in the contain should not be hard coded but read from the fixture file.

Edit here is my JSON file:

```
[
    {
      "rowId": 1,
      "streamId": "33e24004-04ff-4c44-8d59-c8752b0f43d7",
      "notificationStatus": "Sent",
      "details": {
        "name": "Notification",
        "createdTime": "2022-02-07T11:59:15.423Z",
        "createdBy": "test@test.com",
      }
]
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of your json file ?

Comment: @AlapanDas added

Answer (score 1):

You can directly replace the hardcoded values with the values from the json file like this:

```js
it('Fixture test', () => {
  cy.fixture('AllNotificationStates').then((notifications) => {
    for (let n in notifications) {

      cy.intercept('GET', '**/api', {fixture: 'AllNotificationStates.json'})

      cy.wrap(notifications[n]).should('be.an', 'object').and('contain', {
        rowId: notifications[n].rowId,
        streamId: notifications[n].streamId,
        notificationStatus: notifications[n].notificationStatus,
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the fixture file to access them later in the same test.

```
it('Fixture test' ,() => {
    cy.fixture('AllNotificationStates').then(notifications => {
        // all your fixture checks
        }
      .as('fixtureAllNotStates')

    // some other test code
   
    cy.get('@fixtureAllNotStates').then ( () => {
       // some checks with fixture data
    });
})
```

You can also call the fixture in `beforeEach()` for it to be used across multiple `it` blocks. [This](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as#Fixture) is a good reference for doing that

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to the answers already given:

In the Cypress Docs there are two ways described how you can handle JSON files from the fixtures folder: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#Examples

**1. Option: cy.fixture**

As described in the other answers, you can load your JSON files using `cy.fixture()`:

```
cy.fixture('AllNotificationStates.json').as('AllNotificationStates');

cy.get('@AllNotificationStates').then(() => {
   // assert something
});
```

**2. Option: import**

You can alternatively import your JSON files directly, treat them in the code like normal objects and make your assertions:

```
import AllNotificationStates from '../fixtures/AllNotificationStates.json';
```